# YiinfiniteScroller pagination repeated rows

Tags: php, yii

I am using yii YiinfiniteScroller. There are 260 records.  i have displayed 12 records per page. Initially it loads first 12 records correctly. when i scroll the page, it loads the same 12 records (duplicate) And it repeats continuously when i scrolling only 12 records are repeated every time

Here is the code for view page

```
<?php
                    $this->widget('ext.yiinfinite-scroll.YiinfiniteScroller', array(
                    'contentSelector' => '#Load_addcont',
                    'itemSelector' => 'ul.wlist',
                    'loadingText' => 'Loading next 12 rows...',
                    'donetext' => 'Loading finish.',
                    'pages' => $pages,
                    ));


                ?>
```

Here is the code for controller site

```
$pages = new CPagination($row_count);

            $pages->setPageSize(12);
            $pages->applyLimit($criteria);

            $Wineries = Wineries::model()->findAll($criteria);
            $flags = array();

Yii::log("Pagination Wineries row_count = $row_count page # = " . $pages->getCurrentPage(), 'error', 'actionSelectwineries.end');
Yii::log("Pagination Wineries GET = " . CVarDumper::dumpAsString($_GET), 'error', 'actionSelectwineries.end');
```

What is the problem? why same records are repeating? Pls help me if you know

Comment: do you get the answer ?